# Saving rust_decimal to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, rust, decimal, bson

I'm trying to save a `rust_decimal::Decimal` object in MongoDB.

My first attempt was generally:

```rust
// self.db is of type mongodb::sync::Database

decimal = Decimal::new(1, 20);
let order = doc! {"decimal": decimal};
self.db.collection("collection").insert_one(order, None).unwrap();
```

Which yielded the error: `the trait 'From<Decimal>'  is not implemented for 'Bson'`

This led me to learn about the `bson` crate. In its documentation I found about `Decimal128`, which Mongo supports, but it doesn't seem to have a convenient way to convert from either `Decimal` or `String` or anything really.

How do I insert the `Decimal` object to the document?

Crates versions:
`mongodb 2.2.2`
`bson 2.3.0`
`rust_decimal 1.24.0`

Edit: I've tried `Decimal128::from_bytes(decimal.serialize())` but it turns 1 in Decimal to 4.294967296E-6167 in Decimal128 (little/big endian issue?).

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for [`Decimal128`](https://docs.rs/bson/latest/bson/decimal128/struct.Decimal128.html) explicitly states:

> Currently, this type can only be used to round-trip through BSON. See [RUST-36](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUST-36) to track the progress towards a complete implementation.

So it cannot be used for that.

Instead, I'd recommend you going through serde. `rust_decimal` supports serde (with various options and feature flags) and so does `bson`. You can serialize types into BSON with [`bson::ser::to_bson()`](https://docs.rs/bson/latest/bson/ser/fn.to_bson.html) or other functions in this module. For example:

```rust
decimal = Decimal::new(1, 20);
let order = doc! {"decimal": to_bson(&decimal).unwrap()};
```

By default this will serialize the decimal as a string, but you can customize that. See the docs for `rust_decimal`.